# Rsync Connect to one server, Backup to another

Tags: ssh, backup, rsync

I would like to run an rsync job which connects to one server and backs everything up to another. These backups should be incremental and we don't want to delete any files.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [rdiff-backup](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/) and [duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/). Both are for exactly what you want, duplicity also adds encryption layer.

You can do this also with rsync alone, but then you are not saving old versions at all.

```
rsync -az /local/folder -e ssh username@remote_host:/backup/folder
```

backups files from `/local/folder` to remote host. Most probably you want to setup public key authentication, otherwise you have to enter your password each time.

You can put commands to crontab with command `crontab -e`. Something like

```
12 03 * * * your_commands
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at rdiff-backup looks like it'll do the trick

Answer (score 1):

set something like this to run on a cron job and it'll make incremental backups with rsync via SSH:

```
rsync -azvr --rsh="ssh -l theusername -p 22" your.remote.ip.address.or.domain:/remote/path/ /local/path/on/backup/machine/
```

azvr meaning archive, compress, verbose and go recursively into directories, plus this gives the option of running on a different port (which I had a hard time finding an answer to), plus it saves files on the backup that you later delete on the original

Comment: What happens if the connection goes down half way though a large file or an entire job, is rysnc smart enough to carry on?

Comment: @Tom: yes, it's. Whole point of rsync is incremental transfers.

Comment: So will rsync actually detect that the connection is broken, wait a little while and restart or do I just run the same command again and it'll pick where it left of?

Comment: If it's on a cron job, it'll just pick it up again when your cron comes around again. But yeah, it'll pick up where it left off. I believe it's a byte-level copy so it'll detect the differences between files so it'll pick up where it left off.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at backuppc which will do rsync backups.  It can be configured for incremental and full backups.  After the first backup, transfers are incremental.  There is a good web-based interface for querying status, backups, and doing recoveries.

Answer (score 0):

rsync have many powerfull options. check this [link](http://techtrunch.com/commands/rsync-fast-versatile-remote-local-filecopying-tool)

Example:

```
rsync -avz --progress --stats -e ssh /home 192.168.1.23:/backup/home
```

Don'f forget to create SSH keys.